# Why is biblatex-publist producing odd year appendings in reference list

Tags: biblatex-publist

I really can't reproduce this with an MWE, but why is biblatex publist producing these odd year appendings with letters? There are no other matching references in the citations list that match these, e.g., there is no other K_ss, P__acko, G___fe 2024, so why is it printing K_ss, P__acko G__efe 2024b

[image: referencelist]

I have verified there is only one entry in the bib file for the problematic reference list.

Using the texlive 2023 installation, biblatex 3.19

Code, not reproducible, is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grffile}
\listfiles
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, 
doi=false,
date=year, 
url=false, 
maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}

\plauthorname[Simon]{Kiss}

\addbibresource{/Users/skiss/OneDrive - Wilfrid Laurier University/CV/kiss_publications_zotero.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{invited}{*#1}{#1}}
% check if entry's date >= {yyyy}{mm}{dd} 

\defbibcheck{recent}{%
\iffieldint{year}
{\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2015}
{\skipentry}
{}}
{\skipentry}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\nocite{*}
\section{Research and Scholarship Dossier}

\subsection{Description of Research Programme}

\subsection{Publications and Knowledge Dissemination}
%[*] denotes invited

\printbibliography[title={Peer-Reviewed Journal Articles},type={article}, keyword={journalarticle}, keyword={peerreviewed}, keyword={inprint}, check=recent]
\printbibliography[title={Non-Peer-Reviewed Journal articles}, type={article}, keyword={journalarticle}, keyword={notpeer}, keyword={inprint}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Peer-Reviewed Book Chapters}, keyword={chapter}, notkeyword={forthcoming}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Scholarly Conference Papers}, keyword={conference}, notkeyword={forthcoming}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Reports and Working Papers}, keyword={report}, notkeyword={forthcoming}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Book Reviews}, keyword={bookreview}, notkeyword={forthcoming}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures and Presentations}, keyword={guestlecture}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Op-Eds and Scholarly Blog Posts}, keyword={blog},notkeyword={forthcoming}, check=recent]
%
%\subsection*{Other Scholarship}
%
%\printbibliography[title={Peer Reviews},keyword={peerreview}, check=recent]
%
%%\subsubsection{Grants}
%\printbibliography[title={External Grants}, keyword={grant}, keyword={successful}, notkeyword={forthcoming}, check=recent]
%\printbibliography[title={Datasets}, keyword={data}, check=recent]

%\subsubsection{Pre-Registrations}





\section{Teaching Dossier}

\section{Service Dossier}

\section{Appendix A: Copies of Publications}
\includepdf[pages=-]{/Users/skiss/OneDrive - Wilfrid Laurier University/my.papers/education_income_divide.pdf}



\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but `\usepackage{grffile}` does nothing at all for 5 years now: the only thing it does is `\PackageInfo{grffile}{This package is an empty stub for compatibility}`

Comment: Great, thanks! I shed many hot tears fighting over spaces in file names.

Comment: spaces in filenames are evil but latex has supported them by default in \input and \includgraphics for over 5 years now (and before that you only needed to `"` quote the spaces

Comment: Hard to say without minimal example file, but I guess it is related to the fact that you use multiple sections without `\refsection`. Splitting the diverse types of publications to individual bib files might also help.